# Issue with ejb-jar.xml Error processing EjbDescriptor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have a strange issue where if the ejb-bar has one bean, all works well, as soon as I've adding another bean, I am getting the above error when deploying to GlassFish.

I have made the second bean almost identical to the first and added the @EJB annotation with the bean name to the class, then I've added a second `<session>` node to the xml file where the "ejb-name" is EXACTLY as I defined the name!
Is there anywhere else I need to make the reference? note that the ejb-jar.xml is in a different project than those two beans.

File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ClinicService </display-name>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>PatientServiceBean</ejb-name>
      <env-entry>
        <description>Site deployment information for the patient service.</description>
        <env-entry-name>SiteInfo</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>Example</env-entry-value>
      </env-entry>
    </session>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>ProviderServiceBean</ejb-name>
      <env-entry>
        <description>Site deployment information for the provider service.</description>
        <env-entry-name>SiteInfo</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>Example</env-entry-value>
      </env-entry>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: 1) I'm almost certain you actually mean ejb-jar.xml and 2) add that file to the question, it's hard to understand your description without seeing the file.

Comment: Yes sorry! I've edit the question to add the file content

Comment: What error are you getting ? Could you post the two beans and the relevant fragment of the application server stack trace ?

Comment: You need to show more of your code and stack traces otherwise you're forcing us to take educated guesses

Comment: I think it was Eclipse issue with cleaning up projects...
Now the WebService is acting up, when using @EJB(beanName="ProviderServiceBean") then the Patient Web service works, the other one is throwing 500 error (when trying to see WSDL) , ugh!! Even in the patient the siteInfo does not work...

Comment: @SteveC, editing the question now.

Comment: I think it was Eclipse acting up, as today I checked and it works...(did not make any changes or redeploy anything, ghosts in the machine...)